# Do you need brackets around Mysql parameters to prevent sql injection?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using nodejs and the mysql npm package and I'm trying to select from a table where other_text =

Here is what it looks like:

```
var query = connection.query(`SELECT id FROM ${tableName} WHERE other_text = ?`,
    attributeName.other_text, function (err, rows) {
    ...
```

I have read that using ? will automatically escape the user entered string. In most of the examples that I see that do this, they have brackets around the 2nd parameter in the query function, like below:

```
var query = connection.query(`SELECT id FROM ${tableName} WHERE other_text = ?`,
    [attributeName.other_text], function (err, rows) {
    ...
```

Are the brackets necessary in order to escape the string that's passed in? It works when I try it, but I don't even know how to test a SQL injection so I don't really know if the brackets are necessary or even correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work _without_ the brackets?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes. I'm just worried that it does not escape the data without the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets represent an array. You can use an array in case you have more values you want to use with your query.

For example, let's say that you want to select multiple columns from the table, and you want to pass them to the statement, you would use something like this:

```
connection.query(`SELECT ?? FROM ${tableName}`,
[col1, col2, col3], function (err, rows) {
```

It also does work in combination with strings, numbers or even objects. Let's say that you want to update the user with id 1 from Users table table. You would do something like this:

```
const tableName = 'users';
const whereCondition = {id: 1};
const whaToUpdate = {name: 'newName'}
const mysql = require('mysql');
const statement = mysql.format('update ?? set ? where ?', [tableName, whaToUpdate , whereCondition]);
```

I also recommend using .format for better code reading.
Finally you would have something like this:

```
connection.query(statement, (error, result, fields) => { });
```

Answer (score 0):

**The bracket uses for passing multiple values. You can use escape function or question mark (?) placeholder to prevent SQL injections. Lets have a look in details:**

We are using mysql node module to provide all example below (Example 1 to Example 5). The below code is necessary to follow those example.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});
```

MySQL **con.query** has overloaded function.

Example 1: it takes **sql string** and **callback** function

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers;
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Example 2: it takes **sql string, parameter** and **callback** function

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ?';
con.query(sql, [adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

> In Example 2, the second parameter uses **[ ]** so that you can pass
> array to provide multiple values as parameter. **Example 3** shows how to pass multiple values in second parameter.

Example 3: Here two values are passed **name** and **address** into **[ ]**

```
var name = 'Amy';
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = ? OR address = ?';
con.query(sql, [name, adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

**Preventing SQL injections**

To prevent SQL injections, you should use **escape** function the values when query values are variables provided by the user.

Example 4: Here we used **escape** function to avoid **SQL injections**

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ' + mysql.escape(adr);
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Example 5: Escape query values by using the **placeholder ?** method

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ?';
con.query(sql, [adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

[More details](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp)