# NodeJS and MSSQL - insert a parm in a where like ... and showing SQL that ran

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have a function that does a SQL query and returns the JSON output.

1. How can I insert a param into a like clause - for example `student_lastname like 'ABC%'` - where ABC will be a param? I can string together the SQL myself if I need to, just trying to follow a best practice and avoid SQL injection.
2. When the SQL below fails to return any rows, how can I show the SQL that it actually ran? Could I do a `console.log(sql.query)` or something like that? For now, I will try using SQL profiler to see what's coming through.

Code:

```
return sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(pool => {
        // Query - how to fold in my parameter in a like statement 
        return pool.request()
        .input('parms_initialLettersLastname', sql.VarChar(50), initialLettersLastname)
        .query("select student_id, student_firstname, student_lastname, student_city, student_state, student_zip from students where student_lastname like '@parms_initialLettersLastname%' ORDER BY student_lastname, student_firstname ")
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log("getStudents:then(result=>"); 
        console.dir(result);
        sql.close(); 
        return result; 
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // ... error checks 
        console.log("DB Error1: " + err); 
        //console.log(pool.request.query);   // how to print out sql to debug error? 
        sql.close(); 
        throw err; 
    })
```

Comment: Create a stored procedure; don't concatenate dynamic SQL. Then you can pass in your parameter and be injection-safe. There is no realistically safe way to concatenate a string literal to a dynamic sql string. This scenario is the quintessential example used when describing injection attacks.

Comment: Couldn't the SQL injection pass through to a parm?  Seems like I would need dynamic exec SQL in the case of using a where like?

Comment: I've seen some things that MySQL can do, but haven't found the corresponding with the mssql module, eg.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181078/do-you-need-brackets-around-mysql-parameters-to-prevent-sql-injection  has a sql.format...

Comment: I'm sure there are node packages which can help with SQL parameterization, but I'll admit, it's not my area of expertise. With regard to the parameter, you'd have to pass it AS a parameter to your SQL; not just concatenate something. This is where it gets a little fuzzy, because you have to find a node package which will allow you to parameterize your SQL. Ideally something which allows you to define a proc name, and a list of parameters which get mapped by the node package, but something like the MySQL approach you mention where the package basically does fancy string replacement works too

Comment: You might look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mssql

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stills looking for the answer, it would be something like this:

```js
return pool.query()
.input('parms_initialLettersLastname', sql.VarChar(50), initialLettersLastname)
.query(`
select student_id, student_firstname, student_lastname, student_city, 
student_state, student_zip 
from students 
where student_lastname like @parms_initialLettersLastname + '%' 
ORDER BY student_lastname, student_firstname
`);
```

You have to concatenate the % as another VarChar.